# Чем отличаются ссылки от указателей в С++

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки, c++-faq

В чем принципиальное отличие ссылки от указателя в С++? Когда лучше использовать ссылку, а когда указатель? Какие ограничения есть у первых, а какие у вторых?

Comment: Уже и забыл,что,существуют ссылки в с++.Никогда не пользовался.Всегда казалось,что,ссылки в с++ введены для "косметики",чтобы не смущать честной народ,воспитанный на современных синтаксисах древними и ужасными сишными письменами.Ссылки для тех,кому не нужны все прелести и возможности указателей,но,необходимо изменять сами переменные а не их копии.Я,вот,лично,не пойму как при работе с железом без указателя через ссылку получить,например,контекст устройства,поскольку там все через пойнтеры и только через них.

Comment: @Roman Пожалуйста, используйте ответы исключительно для ответов. Если у вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, [задайте его](/questions/ask) отдельным вопросом.

Comment: не понятно  откуда такой интерес к этому вопросу, если такой вопрос уже давно был в SO, но добавлю, что  далеко не все было сказано в ответах о ссыльках и указательях...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

***Еще отличия***:

1. Нельзя объявить массив ссылок.
2. У ссылки нет адреса.
3. Существует арифметика указателей, но нет арифметики ссылок.
4. Указатель может иметь «невалидное» значение с которым его можно сравнить перед использованием.

   Если вызывающая сторона не может не передать ссылку, то указатель может иметь специальное значение `nullptr`:

   ```
   void f(int* num, int& num2)
   {
      if(num != nullptr) // if nullptr ignored algorithm
      {
      }
      // can't check num2 on need to use or not
   }
   ```

   http://rextester.com/EQMC52074

   > (***Standart***) 
   >   A null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.13.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type.
5. Ссылка не обладает квалификатором `const`

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   int main()
   {
       std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";

       const int v = 10;
       //int& const r = v; // Ошибка
       const int& r = v;

       enum
       {
           is_const = std::is_const<decltype(r)>::value
       };

       if(!is_const)
           std::cout << "const int& r is not const\n";
       else
           std::cout << "const int& r is const\n";
   }
   ```

#### О весёлом

Некоторые ссылаются на отрывок с интервью с Страуструпом:

> Очевидной реализацией ссылки является (константный) указатель, при каждом использовании которого происходит разыменование. В некоторых случаях компилятор может оптимизировать ссылку таким образом, что во время исполнения вообще не будет существовать объекта, представляющего ссылку.

Другие задают в ответ лишь в один вопрос:

> Чем является реультат разыменовывания указателя?

На тему, нужно ли знать отличия указателя от ссылки, писал Джоэл Спольски в своей статье «[Закон Дырявых Абстракций](http://russian.joelonsoftware.com/Articles/LeakyAbstractions.html)».

Comment: Первый пункт - точно?

Comment: @Qwertiy: По идее, следует из первого пункта принятого ответа.

Comment: @VladD, но ведь массив можно инициализировать сразу?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Это да, но ведь по идее любой массив _не обязательно_ инициализировать, а можно присвоить значение позже? Так пришлось бы подправлять правила для массива, добавлять исключение.

Comment: @VladD, да, верно: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1164306/4928642

Comment: @VladD, не думаю, что пришлось бы. Но да, смысла в этом мало.

Comment: как это ссылки не имеют квалификатора конст? при передаче параметра в функцию повсеместно используются const Object& var, которые не позволяют изменять значение внутри функции.

Comment: @goldstar_labs там имелось виду, что нету константной ссылки, только ссылка на константу.

Comment: Почему у ссылки нет адреса? У ссылки есть адрес. Менять его нельзя - да. Но взять адрес у неё можно так же как и у обычной переменной, через оператор взятия адреса &.

Answer (score 41):

Принципиальных отличий два:

- ссылка, в отличии от указателя, не может быть неинициализированной;
- ссылка не может быть изменена после инициализации.

Отсюда и получаем плюсы и минусы использования того и другого:

- ссылки лучше использовать когда нежелательно или не планируется изменение связи ссылка → объект;
- указатель лучше использовать, когда возможны следующие моменты в течении жизни ссылки:

  - ссылка не указывает ни на какой объект;
  - ссылка указаывает на разные объекты в течении своего времени жизни.

Answer (score 3):

Ссылки проще понять в сравнении с указателями. По сути, это те же указатели, но немного измененные.

Напишу только про обычные ссылки ("lvalue-ссылки" `&`). Про "rvalue-ссылки" `&&` - читать отдельно.

- Ссылки всегда разыменовываются автоматически (после того, как были созданы):

  ```cpp
  int x = 0;                   int x = 0;
  int *y = &x;                 int &y = x;
  *y = 42;                     y = 42; // Не нужно разыменование.
  ```

  - Следствие: Ссылку нельзя "перенацелить" на другой объект, после того, как она создана.

    Если для указателя можно написать `y = &z;`, то для ссылки присваивание меняет объект, на который она ссылается, а не ее саму.

    - Следствие: Ссылку обязательно инициализировать сразу при создании.

      ```cpp
      int *z; /* ок */             int &z; // Ошибка компиляции.
      ```
    - Следствие: Ссылки не бывают константными.

      Поскольку их и так нельзя менять, дополнительный `const` не имеет смысла и запрещен.

      `int *const x` - "`x` - константный указатель на неконстантный `int`". Но `int &const x` - ошибка компиляции.

      Не путать с `const int *x` и `const int &x` - неконстантный указатель/ссылка на константный `int`. Тут оба варианта легальны.
- Ссылки инициализируются не адресом, а самим объектом (см. пример выше).

  Разница только в способе записи, эффект на самом деле одинаковый.

  - Следствие: Ссылки не бывают нулевыми.

    Указатель можно инициализировать `nullptr` - нулевым адресом. А поскольку ссылка инициализируется не адресом, туда указатель не подойдет.

    Попытка создать нулевую ссылку (пример: `int *x = nullptr; int &y = *x;`) вызывает неопределенное поведение. Но компиляторы обычно никак не защищают от этого (вероятнее всего, крашнет при использовании ссылки, а не при создании).

    Но поскольку это UB (т.е. "undefined behavior", т.е. "неопределенное поведение"), проверки а-ля `&ссылка == nullptr` не имеют никакого смысла, поскольку могут быть выброшены компилятором как всегда ложные.

И указатели, и ссылки часто используют как параметры функций - когда передавать по значению не хочется (либо потому, что нужно изменить параметр и видеть изменения снаружи функции, либо потому, что тип параметра дорого копировать). Соответственно, чаще всего указатели - для опциональных параметров (вместо которых можно передать ноль), а ссылки - для обязательных.

Чтобы передать в функцию массив, традиционно используют указатель на первый элемент, хотя чисто с точки зрения языка, ссылка на первый элемент ничем не хуже.

Некоторые не любят использовать неконстантные ссылки в параметрах. Дескать, нагляднее писать `&` при вызове, чтобы сразу видеть, что объект меняется.

- И указатели и ссылки нельзя инициализировать rvalue (грубо говоря, временными объектами, у которых компилятор не дает взять адрес):

  ```cpp
  int *x = &42; // ошибка компиляции, сразу на `&`.
  int &y = 42; // ошибка компиляции
  ```

  - Исключение: Ссылки на константные типы - можно.

  ```cpp
  const int &z = 42; // ок
  ```

---

Дальше идут тонкости.

- Ссылки продляют время жизни временных объектов.

  ```cpp
  const int &x = 42;
  int y = x;
  ```

  Этот пример легален. Временный объект, на который указывает ссылка, продляет свое время жизни до времени жизни ссылки.

  Но в этом правиле [много исключений](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary), например при возврате ссылки из функции это не действует. Никаких принципально новых возможностей эта фича не дает, поэтому проще вообще не пользоваться.
- Ссылки не являются объектами.

  Это больше формальность в стандарте, и тут нужно объяснение.

  Объект - это просто экземпляр какого-то типа, с именем или без. Например, `int x` - объект типа `int`, и `42` - тоже. (Исключение: функции - не объекты.)

  Переменная - это, грубо говоря, объект с именем. `int x` - переменная, а `42` - нет. (Хотя исключения есть. Например, безымянные параметры функций - тоже переменные.)

  И второе исключение: ссылки - это переменные, но не объекты. Т.е. `int &x` - переменная но не объект, а `int x` - одновременно и переменная и объект.

  Поэтому, более точное определение переменной - это "то, что было объявлено (если это не функция)". Т.е. `x` - переменная, если где-то выше есть объявление `int x;`. А `42` - нет, потому что для нее ничего такого нет.

  - Следствие: Формально, у ссылок нет адресов.

    `&ссылка` выдает адрес не самой ссылки, а того, на что она указывает (это следует из того, что ссылки разыменовываются автоматически).

    Можно положить ссылку в структуру, и взять адрес структуры. Технически, по этому адресу как раз будет лежать ссылка (в виде указателя), но формально - по этому адресу непонятно что.

    - Следствие: Менять какие-то байтики по "адресу" ссылки - UB.
  - Следствие: Не бывает указателей на ссылки, массивов ссылок.
- Выражения не могут иметь типы-ссылки.

  Это тоже больше формальность.

  У внимательного читателя мог возникнуть вопрос: Если не бывает объектов-ссылок, то чем будет являться возвращенная из функции ссылка? Ведь не переменной, имени-то у нее нет, и объявлена она не была.

  Сначала поясняю, что такое выражение. Классическое определение - это "операнды, соединенные операторами". Т.е. `1 + 1`, `(2 * 3) + 4`, и т.п. Отдельные операнды - это тоже выражения, например `42` или `x` (если выше есть `int x;`).

  Выражение - это часть исходного кода программы (грамматический термин), а не то, что существует в памяти (то - объекты).

  Выражение *ссылаются* на объекты. Например, `1 + 1` ссылается на временный объект int со значением 2. А `x` ссылается на объект и переменную `int x;` (если такая объявлена выше).

  Rvalue и lvalue - это свойства выражений (т.н. "категория выражения"), а "временный" и "не временный" - свойства объектов.

  Так вот, выражения не могут иметь типы-ссылки.

  Т.е. если имеем `int &x`, то выражение `x` - это lvalue типа `int` (ссылкой оно быть не может). Аналогично, если есть `int y`, то выражение `y` - тоже lvalue типа `int`.

  Аналогично, если имеем `int &x()`, то `x()` - lvalue типа int. А для `int y()`, `y()` - rvalue типа int.