# Передача в функцию указателя или ссылки

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

В чем будет разница, если в функцию передать указатель и ссылку?
например

```
#include <iostream>  
void func(int *a)
{
  *a = 5
}
int main()
{
  int a;
  func(a);
  std::cout << a;
}
```

и

```
#include <iostream>  
void func(int &a)
{
  a = 5
}
int main()
{
  int a;
  func(a);
 std::cout << a;
}
```

Программы выведут одно и то же?
Ведь и так, и так мы обращаемся к существующему элементу, а не создаем новый.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В принципе, технически разница между указателем и ссылкой лишь в том, что саму ссылку нельзя изменить (а указатель можно). [[Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/349/10105) бóльший список отличий.] Кроме этого, разница ещё синтаксическая: с ссылкой вы обращаетесь как будто это переменная, а с указателем нужно его правильно получать/разыменовывать:

```
void func(int *a)
{
  *a = 5;
}
int main()
{
  int a;
  func(&a);
  cout << a;
}
```

Других технических отличий нет, и результат будет одинаковый.

Но разница на самом деле не в синтаксисе, а в смысле, в семантике.

Указатель может означать всё, что угодно. Он в C и C++ означает строку, ассив, адрес переменной, передачу переменной по ссылке и ещё кучу всяких вещей. А смысл ссылки ровно один — это как бы альтернативное имя (alias) существующей переменной.

Поэтому для случаев наподобие того, который вы описали, в C++ уместно использовать ссылку, а не указатель. Хотя, как вы сами видите, с указателем тоже прекрасно работает.

И ещё: в чистом C ссылок нет, так что у вас нет другого варианта кроме указателей.

Answer (score 7):

Ответы на ваш вопрос даны выше, разницы в поведении никакой, но хотел бы уточнить несколько нюансов.
**1.** Пока у вас простые типы разницы никакой (кроме описаной выше в других ответах, например про NULL значение переменной в случае указателя).
Но как только дело дойдет до классов появится разница.
В случае передачи в функцию указателя на класс то, в зависимости от реализации и решаемых задач, будет иметь место разыменовывание указателя. Сложность этой процедуры будет зависеть от размера класса. Это справделиво в случе разыменовывания всего класса и не касается доступа к отдельным его членам. Например: `int c = b->d; //дешево`, а `A b = *A; //дороже`
**2.** вы можете перегрузить оператор `&`, а `*` нет.
**3.** Указатели не могут принимать временные значения, в то время как `const &` могут. Например: `void f(const &A);.... f(A()); //возможно` 
**4.** В целом работа с ссылками проще, поэтому ведут к меньшему числу ошибок

Золотое правило с++ программиста: используй ссылки где можешь, а указатели где должен.

Comment: +1 за возможную перегрузку

Comment: @VladD спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Если вы исправите опечатки и включите заголовок

```
#include <iostream>

void func(int *a)
{
  *a = 5;
  ^^    ^
}
int main()
{
  int a;
  func(a);
  std::cout << a;
  ^^^^^
}
```

и

```
#include <iostream>

void func(int &a)
{
  a = 5;
       ^
}
int main()
{
  int a;
  func(a);
  std::cout << a;
  ^^^^^
}
```

То вывод будет идентичен.

Когда используются указатели, то вы можете передать null-указатель. Например,

```
void func(int *a)
{
    if ( a ) *a = 5;
}
```

И функция может быть вызвана как

```
int x;

func( &x );
func( nullptr );
```

Когда же используются ссылки, то ссылка должна указывать на существующий объект.