# Использование перегруженного оператора

Tags: c++, ооп, перегрузка-операторов, операторы

В данном коде `ob[i]` является элементом выражения, которое не может "быть изменено левосторонним значением" :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 3;

class atype {
    int a[SIZE];
public:
    atype() {
        register int i;
        for (i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) a[i] = i;
    }
    int operator[](int i) { return a[i]; }
};

int main()
{
    atype ob;
    cout << ob[2] << endl; // отображает число 2
    ob[2] = 25;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Но если мы укажем, что значение, которое возвращает перегруженная функция является ссылкой, программа начинает работать :

```
int &operator[](int i) { return a[i]; }
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу понять, как это работает. Каким образом это изменение позволяет нам использовать оператор `[]` слева от оператора присваивания?

Comment: нуу..ссылка возвращает то, что может быть изменено.Без ссылки функция возвращает константу, т.е. ,например, `2 = 25` - что есть безсмысленно

Comment: @Artem Aleksandrovich, нет, это не так, и нет бессмысленности, а  невозможно присвоить что либо тому, чего просто нет

Comment: Вам нужно почитать о том, что такое ссылка. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/349/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%A1

Comment: Не "не может быть изменено левосторонним значением", а "не может быть *изменяемым* левосторонним значением".

Answer (score 4):

По сути, в первом случае вы возвращаете *значение* - т.е. при попытке присваивания у вас получается что-то типа

```
5 = 10;
```

А вот если вы возвращаете *ссылку*, то это, грубо говоря, псевдоним переменной, так что получается фактически место в памяти, где это значение хранится. Поэтому при присвоении *ему* компилятор знает, куда записать значение, а при присвоении *его* - откуда значение взять.

Где-то так...

Answer (score 0):

При возвращении  (если это не ссылька )  обьект копируется, и вы получаете совсем другой обьект, не имеющий никакого отношения с элементом массива.

Присваивание  `ob[2] = 25;` означает

```
// первое выражение
int n = ob[2];
// второе выражение
n = 25;
```

так как обьект `n` (я дал имя лишь для наглядности) просто временное переменное, то нельзя  присвоить ему что либо (его уже не существует после первого выражения)...
Ну а ссылька это имя вашего элемента и есть `lvalue`...
P. S. никакого `2 = 25` или `5 = 10` тут нет