# В чём разница между этими объявлениями указателя?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Можете, пожалуйста, сказать, чем отличаются эти строки `ptr1` и `ptr2`? Работают они, вроде бы, одинаково.

```
int mas[5] = {1, 2, 3, 8};    
const int *ptr1 = mas;
const int (&ptr2)[5] = mas;
```

Comment: В вашем примере есть только одно объявление указателя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое действительно объявляет указатель, второе - объявляет ссылку (так как ссылка на массив, оно может неявно преобразовываться в указатель, как и сам массив).

Answer (score 2):

`ptr1` - это указатель на `const int`, инициализированный адресом нулевого элемента массива `mas`. По сути, это будет равносильно записи вида:

```
ptr1 = &mas[0];
```

Такой указатель можно в дальнейшем переназначить, например:

```
ptr1 = &mas[1];
```

Или на любую другую переменную вовсе не связанную с массивом:

```
int i = 42;
ptr1 = &i;
```

Но менять данные через такой указатель нельзя из-за `const` в объявлении. Т.е. нельзя сделать так:

```
*ptr1 = 100500;
```

`ptr2` - это ссылка на массив из пяти `const int`. По сути второе имя массива `mas`, но с наложенной на него константностью. Данные через такую ссылку так же нельзя менять. Но здесь ещё вступает в силу и само ограничение ссылок - их нельзя переназначать. Т.е. нельзя выполнить такое после инициализации:

```
ptr2 = mas;
```

В общем, вопрос отличия указателей от ссылок - это уже [отдельный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/349/176217).

Answer (score 2):

Ключевое отличие этих способов - вот в чем:

```
std::cout << sizeof ptr1 <<std::endl; // 4 или 8 - зависит от битности системы
std::cout << sizeof *ptr1 <<std::endl; // 4 (скорее всего)
std::cout << sizeof ptr2 <<std::endl; // 20
```

Когда вы объявляете указатель и присваиваете ему массив - вы теряете информацию о размере массива, остается лишь указатель на первый элемент.

Когда вы объявляете ссылку на массив - информация о размере сохраняется и может быть получена через sizeof.

Второе по важности отличие - указатель является изменяемым типом данных, без дополнительного `const` указателю можно присвоить какое-нибудь другое значение. Ссылка же связывается со своим начальным значением на всю жизнь.

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае:

```
const int *ptr = mas;
```

`ptr` — это указатель на `const int`, который вы инициализируете массивом. Однако, массив `mas` неявно преобразуется к указателю на свой первый элемент и, следовательно, `ptr` указывает на первый элемент массива `mas`.

Если бы вы написали так:

```
const int (*ptr2)[5] = &mas;
```

то `ptr2` был бы указателем на массив из пяти элементов типа `const int`. Указатель на массив — это не тоже самое, что указатель на первый элемент массива.

Например, обратиться к элементу массива `mas` с индексом `1` можно так `ptr[1]`, или так `(*ptr2)[1]`.

Однако, запись `ptr2[1]` — это попытка обращения к объекту, первый байт которого начинается с байта, следующего непосредственно за последним байтом массива `mass`. А запись `(*ptr)[1]` и вовсе является некорректной.

Теперь касательно ссылок. Ссылка — это что-то вроде альтернативного имени для некоторого объекта (На строгость и полное соответствие стандарту языка C++ не претендую :) ). По аналогии с указателями, вы можете объявить ссылку как на некоторый элемент массива `mas`:

```
const int &r = mas[1]; //Ссылка на второй элемент массива mas;
```

так и на весь массив:

```
const int (&r2)[5] = mas;
```

Небольшой пример, демонстрирующий некоторые свойства ссылок и указателей:

```
int mas[5] = {1, 2, 3, 8};

const int *ptr = mas;
int (*ptr2)[5] = &mas;

const int &r = mas[1];
const int (&r2)[5] = mas;

cout << uintptr_t(ptr + 1)  - uintptr_t(ptr)  << " " << sizeof(int) << " " << sizeof(r)  << endl;
cout << uintptr_t(ptr2 + 1) - uintptr_t(ptr2) << " " << sizeof(mas) << " " << sizeof(r2) << endl;
cout << sizeof(ptr) << " " << sizeof(*ptr) << " " << sizeof(ptr2) << " " << sizeof(*ptr2) << endl;

mas[1] = 42; (*ptr2)[2] = 24;
cout << r << " " << r2[2] << endl;
ptr = &mas[3];
cout << *ptr << endl;
```

Возможный вывод этой программы будет таким:

```
4 4 4
20 20 20
8 4 8 20
42 24
8
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, чем (*ptr2)[1] из вашего примера отличается от ptr[1]?

Comment: @wololo что мне мешает написть так: const int *ptr = mas; cout << ptr[1] << endl;?

Comment: @YuryMelnikov, ничто не мешает.

Comment: @МишаковМаксим, исправил ответ.