# Разница между указателем и ссылкой

Tags: c++, c, массивы, указатели

Я не понимаю, почему выводит разные значения, разве ссылка не должна неявно преобразовываться в указатель на `mas`?

```
int mas[5] = {1, 2, 3, 8};
const int *ptr = mas;
qDebug() << &ptr // Output: 0x28fe30;
qDebug() << ptr // Output: 0x28fe34;
```

Comment: см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/349/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%A1

Answer (score 5):

В вашем коде нет ссылок, `&ptr` является указателем на указатель.

Comment: Т.е он указывает на адрес самого ptr, а не значения в нём? Если это так, то почему адрес указателя меньше адреса массива? Массив же был раньше инициализирован

Comment: @МишаковМаксим Да. Вам стоит ознакомиться с базовым синтаксисом для объявления ссылок и указателей. Адреса могут быть в любом порядке, инициализация тоже.

Comment: @МишаковМаксим У вас переменные на стеке. Стек в памяти растет сверху вниз.

Comment: @МишаковМаксим Чтобы указывало на значение, нужно использовать операторы `*` или `[]`.

Comment: @ VTT , если только это не адреса элементов массива

Answer (score 1):

Не нулевой указатель,  является последовательностью битов, т. е. занимает место в памяти,  если он ссылается на обьект или на другой указатель. Значение указателья это адрес обьекта `obj`. Мы говорим, что данный указатель указывает на `obj`.
Ссыльки не занимают место в памяти, они лишь являются именами (индентификаторами).
Т. е. мы обращаемся со ссылькой на обьект `obj` также, как обратились бы к самому `obj`...

Comment: Какая-то ерунда про место в памяти.

Comment: ерунда что   - формулировка или что  выделяется память под указатель?...

Comment: выделяется память под указатель в случае использования ссылки

Comment: ну значит формулировка - спасибо, сейчась допишу

Comment: "Ссыльки не занимают место в памяти, они лишь являются именами (индентификаторами)" Если ссылка не занимает памяти, как процессор понимает на какой объект указывает данная ссылка и как он различает разные ссылки

Comment: @ Unick,  int a = 0;  int& b = a; выделяется память и  для буквы a и lдля буквы b, или все таки под int?... По вашему как?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan выделяется память под int (a) и под указатель(b). На уровне исполнения программы ссылка ничем не отличается от указателя.

Comment: @Qwertiy, @Unick, зря набросились на товарища. С точки зрения стандарта языка, ссылка — это не объект, и памяти в хранилище не занимает. Вы не можете получить размер ссылка в байтах, используя `sizeof`, вы не можете взять адрес ссылки, используя `&`.

Comment: А уж каким именно образом, конкретные реализации реализуют ссылки — это другой вопрос.

Comment: @wololo, никто ни на кого не накинулся. Просто в ответе присутсвуют двусмысленные фразы, которые можно неправильно понять.

Comment: @ Unick, не согласен - ссылька  это есть адрес начала обьекта (обьект может быть большим), того обьекта, на который ссылаемся, и нет у самой ссыльки адреса

Comment: @ Unick , скомпилится, но это будет адрес обьекта  "a" - не другой адрес

Comment: @ARHovsepyan мне кажется мы с вами говорили о ссылка на разных уровнях абстракции. С точки зрения языка все верно ссылка это "индентификатор", который имеет отличее от указателя. Если заглянуть в ассемблер работа с ссылкой и указателем ничем не отличается (во всяком случае мне не известна реализация, которая с ссылками работала особым образом).

Comment: @wololo, если что-то не занимает памяти, оно не существует: например, `void`. Но чтобы передать ссылку в функцию, надо где-то потратить 8 байт (ну или 4) на указатель. А не магические 0 байт на то, что код должен откуда-то сам угадать, какую же ссылку мы хотим ему передать.

Comment: @ Unick ,  я компиляторы не писал, не знаю как реализована хранения ссылок- может это хэш таблица как  для виртуальных функций,  может это char* для всех ссылок на обьект, но если я не прав, значит и Страуструп и другие авторы учебников  врут, потому что я во всех книгах читал то же обьяснение  о ссыльках.

Comment: @ Qwertiy, для реализации класса , который содержит пару обьектов, могут быть использованы несколько десятков обьектов, но это не значит, что обьект класса занимает память  этих десятков обьектов.  Так что реализиауия и сущность, разные вещи... Я не против того, что у меня плохо получается обьяснять, но могу за собой оставить право не согласиться с вами...

Answer (score 0):

У тебя амперсанд указывает, что ты обращаешься к области памяти, где лежит твой указатель ptr. То есть выводишь адрес ЭТОГО указателя.
Во втором случае ты обращаешься к ДАННЫМ в области памяти, на которую указывает ptr, поэтому и результат разный.
То есть тут амперсанд берет адрес адреса ячейки массива.
Если я правильно понимаю)