# Параметр функции в c++

Tags: c++, функции, ссылки, параметры

- `void f(int i) {}` -- эта функция ожидает получить один параметр int
  и не вернёт ничего.
- `void f(int *i){}` -- эта ожидает указатель, я так понимаю.
- `void f(int &i){}` -- что ожидает на входе эта функция?

Comment: Почитайте литературу о *ссылках* в С++. Ссылки в С++ - слишком обширная тема, чтобы пытаться покрыть ее в одном вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вкратце можно сказать следующее.

Параметр этой функции

void f(int &i){}

определяет так называемую `lvalue` ссылку.

Такое определение функции позволяет изменить аргумент, переданный функции, так как в функцию передается не копия значения аргумента, а аргумент передается по ссылке. Например,

```
#include <iostream>

void g( int i )
{
    i += 10;
}

void h( int &i )
{
    i += 10;
}

int main() 
{
    int i = 0;

    std::cout << "Before call g( i ) i = " << i << '\n';
    g( i );
    std::cout << "After  call g( i ) i = " << i << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "Before call h( i ) i = " << i << '\n';
    h( i );
    std::cout << "After  call h( i ) i = " << i << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
Before call g( i ) i = 0
After  call g( i ) i = 0

Before call h( i ) i = 0
After  call h( i ) i = 10
```

То есть функция `g` имеет дело с копией значения переменной `i`. Сама исходная переменная `i`, объявленная в `main`, не изменяется.

С другой стороны, функция `h` изменяет исходную переменную `i`, так как она передается в функцию по ссылке.

Имейте в виду, что можно параметр функции объявить также как

```
int &&i
```

Это так-называемая `rvalue` ссылка, предназначенная для работы с временными объектами.

Рассмотрите такую программу.

```
#include <iostream>

void f( int && )
{
    std::cout << "void f( int && )\n";
}

void f( int * )
{
    std::cout << "void f( int * )\n";
}

void f( int & )
{
    std::cout << "void f( int &  )\n";
}

int main() 
{
    int i = 0;

    f( 0 );

    f( i );

    f( &i );

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
void f( int && )
void f( int &  )
void f( int * )
```

Comment: Я так понял: `f(int)` создаёт копию, которая будет удалена из памяти после действа, а `f(int&)` имеет доступ напрямую к значению и может его изменить. В таком случае чем отличается `f(int)` от `f(const int &)`? Второй вариант съест памяти на один int меньше и всё?

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин Вы правильно поняли. Передача константной ссылки на объект позволяет сэкономить память, так как порой в качестве аргументов могут использоваться большие классы или классы с ресурсо-емкими конструкторами.

Comment: Тогда ещё вопрос: если функция `f(const class-name &class-example)` совершает действия, в расчётах пользует public-поля экземпляра класса class-name с именем class-example, а в это время другой поток (thread) имея полный доступ к class-example меняет значения public-полей, то функция будет пользовать новые значения полей или у неё есть шанс "выловить" мусор, пока действо в другом потоке начато и не завершено? например `class-example->var0=1+3+2` в другом потоке даст функции значение поля `var0` равное 6 или некоторое время во время расчётов там будет мусор?

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин Вам следует синхронизировать доступ в этом случае.

Comment: и ещё вопрос: если в коде есть `func(int i)` и `func(int &i)` одновременно, затем будет примерно следующее: `int a =1; int b = func(a);`, то какая из них будет использована? И что делать, если мне действительно нужно оба этих варианта, чтобы пользовать нужный в случае необходимости создания копии или не создания копии входящих данных?

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин Будет ошибка неоднозначности вызова.

Answer (score 0):

Короткий ответ: эта функция ожидает на входе lvalue типа `int`. Параметр-ссылка `i` будет привязана к тому lvalue, которое вы передадите в качестве аргумента.

Длинный ответ: Почитайте литературу о ссылках в C++. Ссылки в C++ - базовое свойство языка C++ и слишком обширная тема, чтобы пытаться покрыть ее в одном ответе.

[Чем отличаются ссылки от указателей в С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/349/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%A1)