# Ссылка на указатель vs указатель на указатель. C++

Tags: c++, указатели

Есть ли какая-либо разница в производительности или вообще какие-либо За и Против использования такой конструкции:

```
Type* a = new Type();
Type*&b = a;
```

в противовес обычному указателю на указатель:

```
Type* a = new Type();
Type* b = a;
```

Visual studio 2019 выдала мне [такой](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYpHo.jpg) асм с `int` примером.

Ранее часто сталкивался с утверждением, что ссылка **бесплатна**, в то время, как указатель нет, но не говорит ли приведенный пример ассемблерного кода, что это не так?

---

*зы:*

Предположим у нас есть массив `*&` (инициализируем в конструкторе) либо `const *` `+-10'000` элементов. 

Элементы не меняются данным классом, только дергаем их поля для дальнейшего использования и обработки нашим классом.

Соответственно вопрос: будет ли какой-то выигрыш в случае использования `*&`, или, по идее, `const pointer` уже будет достаточно оптимизирован компилятором и будет хранится/обрабатываться примерно как ссылка на более низком уровне?

---

Буду благодарен за Ваши разъяснения в этом вопросе.

Comment: Вставляйте картинки прямо в текст сообщений, на внешних ресурсах они могут протухнуть. Ну а ещё лучше - вставлять текстом, если содержимое по сути именно текстовое.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, возьму на заметку, спасибо

Comment: Ну и в примере у вас нет указателя на указатель. Нужно тогда `Type** b = &a;` во втором случае.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, да, я немного неправильно выразился про указатель на указатель, но идея, полагаю, понятна. Про эти отличия я знаю, информация в вопросе, который Вы прислали тоже известна, просто интересовал конкретно приведенный мною пример и использования такого кода. Просто прежде не сталкивался с реальным кодом, где используют подобную конструкцию `*&`, поэтому и возник этот вопрос. Плюс основной  интерес был именно к разнице в производительности.

Comment: Откорректируйте вопрос, чтобы он отражал проблему с учётом выясненных в комментариях подробностей. Кнопка [edit] под текстом вопроса.

Comment: В том то и дело, что идея совершенно не понятна. Если бы у вас действительно был указатель на указатель, то идея была бы понятна. А так - конструкции очевидным образом неэквивалентны и вопроса "противовеса" между ними не возникает.

Answer (score 4):

С точки зрения низкоуровневых реализаций ссылка будет вести себя практически так же как и указатель. К тому же, оптимизатор может вообще многое перекроить и повыкидывать. Рекомендую пользоваться базовыми правилами по выбору ссылка или указатель:

- Если нужно ввести некий постоянный синоним какой-то сущности, не предполагающий переустановку на другой объект - используйте ссылку;
- Иначе - используйте указатель.

Дополнительно можно глянуть ещё вот в этот вопрос: [Чем отличаются ссылки от указателей в С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/349/176217)