# В чем разница передачи аргументов по ссылке и через указатель?

Tags: c++

В чем разница передачи аргументов по ссылке и через указатель?
Ведь и в том и в том случае мы работаем с адресом переданного объекта.

```
void func(int &a)
{
    std::cout << a;
}

void func(int *a)
{
    std::cout << *a;
}
```

Comment: В случае когда вызываемая функция получает аргумент по ссылке, при просмотре программистом кода,  он не может понять (не посмотрев на прототип) , может ли эта функция изменить передаваемую переменную. Для практики программирования это большой минус в использовании С++, по сравнению с передачей по указателю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основное отличие в том что ссылка разыменовывается автоматически и вам не нужно при вызове функции явно указывать, что вы передаете указатель.
И ссылок не было в чистом си,они появились в с++.

[Более подробно о тонкостях в аналогичном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/349/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%A1)

Answer (score 2):

- Передача ссылки не обязательно подразумевает работу с адресом переданного объекта.
- При передаче указателя возможна передача нулевого указателя, т.е. это опциональный аргумент.
- При передаче ненулевого указателя он может указывать как на отдельный объект, так и на первый объект из массива из нескольких объектов.
- При передаче указателя возможна передача владения, то бишь ответственности за вызов подходящей функции удаления (`delete` `free` и т.п.).

Comment: (3) и (4) одинаково хорошо работают и со ссылками, и с указателями. На счет (1) непонятно, какое практическое значение это имеет, если внутри все равно происходит передача адреса.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Передача ссылки не обязательно подразумевает передачу адреса, компилятор может запросто и по значению передать и через смещение. Ну нет, ссылка всегда указывает строго на один объект, а указатель - от 0 до произвольного числа. В принципе можно извратится и передавать владение через ссылку, но это явно использование ссылки не по назначению и все равно потребует преобразование ее в адрес.

Comment: На счет *"указывает на один объект"* - я же могу передать ссылку, например, на первый элемент массива, а потом сделать `(&ref)[i]`. На счет *"передача ссылки не обязательно подразумевает передачу адреса"* - если компилятор не видит тело функции, то он не знает, будут ли брать адрес у ссылки, поэтому должен передавать по указателю, на случай если этот адрес потребуется. А если он видит тело функции, то он по идее и передачу по указателю может заменить на передачу по значению, если указатель в функции всегда разыменовывается и сам адрес не используется.

Answer (score 0):

Единственное заметное отличие: указатель может быть нулевым,  а ссылка нет - она всегда должна указывать на какой-то объект (попытка создать ссылку из нулевого указателя вызывает неопределенное поведение).

Но на уровне машинного кода между передачей по указателю и по ссылке [не должно быть разницы](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#reference-parameter), и нет какой-то защиты от создания нулевых ссылок.

---

Еще небольшая разница в том, что в указатель можно записать новый адрес, и из него можно получить указатель (или ссылку) на указатель, если это зачем-то нужно.

Comment: в теории да, ссылка не может быть нулевой... а на практике... И потом смотришь в отладчик и не понимаешь, что происходит.  Поэтому, на практике ссылка бывает иногда "нулевой" - просто кто то решил, что указатель у него никогда не будет nullptr и добавил звездочку без проверок.