# Чем int& a отличается от int* a?

Tags: c++

Что такое за конструкция: `int& a` она чем-то отличается от `int* a`?

Comment: ссылку не узнали? это как бы совсем базовый си++

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Чем отличаются ссылки от указателей в С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/349/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%a1)