# Переменная и указатель

Tags: c++, c, указатели, выделение-памяти, информатика

Я давно изучал язык СИ, сейчас изучаю другой, но до сих пор не могу до конца понять базовую вещь - указатели.

Я знаю, что переменная занимает место в памяти, в зависимости от типа:

- int - 4байта
- char - 1байт
- ...
- void* - 8байт(как и любой указатель)

Переменные хранят в себе значения. Указатели так же, но значением является адрес другой переменной.

А не понимаю я вот что: эти 4 байта для int(к примеру) физически лежат в памяти. Если мы хотим получить доступ к ячейкам памяти, то нам все же где-то нужно хранить указатель на них!?
Получается любая переменная по факту занимает 8 байт и разделение на простая и указатель переменная есть ни что иное как синтаксический сахр?

Comment: Разные компиляторы по разному. borland c++ 3.0 - у него int 2 байта. x86 - int = 4 байта, а в x64 сборка int = 4 байта, но выравнивание 8 байт, поэтому для кросспатформ используют int8_t int16_t int32_t и т п. Если пакуется в структуры - нужно отключать паковку байт, что бы тип данных не расширялся, ещё в кросс-платформенных программах учитывается, что часть платформ читает байты слева-направо, а часть наоборот.

Comment: sizeof(void*) в x86 win сборке 4 байта это точно (очень удобно в int хранить было), в x64 win 8 байт, в borland c++ 3.0  2 байта.

Comment: Для x64 - Смотря где переменная находится, если переменная в массиве - то данные спаковываются, и размер int[2] и int[1] будет фактически равен из-за align8. Если переменная в глобальной памяти или в стеке, она будет занимать кратно 8 из-за align8, если переменная в "packet" struct то она будет занимать столько сколько должна 4, а не больше.

Comment: @nick_n_a по-моему вы упускаете суть вопроса

Comment: Я думал написать про то, что размеры типов примерны, но не стал. Друзья, про различную наполненость типов, в зависимости от внешних факторов, я знаю, но вопрос не в этом.

Comment: *[куча опечаток, перепечатал свои комментарии]* Значение локальной (например) переменной хранится в стеке, а адрес стека хранится где-то в регистрах процессора (в частности, x86 регистр %rsp хранит адрес вершины стека), поэтому никакие дополнительные указатели хранить не требуется. Впрочем, если повезёт и компилятор сможет соптимизировать локальную переменную, то может оказаться так, что она вообще целиком переедет в регистры процессора и никак не будет занимать оперативную память

Comment: Просто для демонстрации некорректности ваших рассуждений — давайте (полагая что вы правы, и к 4 байтам нужны еще 8 для адреса) рекурсивно спросим себя, но ведь эти 8 где-то тоже хранятся в памяти, и "*нам все же где-то нужно хранить указатель на них!?*" — итак, уже 4+8\*2. Но и этот адрес тоже надо где-то хранить, так что... Да как вообще программа может работать на компьютере без бесконечной памяти? :) Все дело в том, что, огрубляя, для переменных адреса в памяти не хранятся, а вычисляются еще на этапе компиляции (опять же, с массой тонкостей) и используются в коде, по сути, непосредственно.

Comment: Для статических переменных - адрес это константа вычисленная при компиляции, для локальных - константа-смещение к стеку также вычисленная при компиляции и нигде они run time не хранятся

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Если мы хотим получить доступ к ячейкам памяти, то нам все же где-то нужно хранить указатель

Да.

> разделение на простая и указатель переменная есть ни что иное как синтаксический сахр?

Нет.

Есть два основных вида *переменных*:

- Глобальные и статические — их адреса известны во время линковки (или [задаются один раз при запуске приложения](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)#Load-time)), и в каком-то виде зашиваются прямо в код, который к ним обращается.
- На стеке — в одном из регистров обычно хранится указатель на верхушку стека, а к переменным обращаются по смещению относительно этого указателя. Смещение зашивается в код, который к ним обращается.

  Либо такие переменные могут быть соптимизированы и храниться в регистрах, тогда в код зашивается, какой именно это регистр.

Объекты в куче не являются переменными, потому что у них нет имен (грубо говоря). И для них нет какого-то автоматического вычисления адреса. К ним можно обратиться только через указатель вручную (так же, как можно обратиться к любому другому объекту).

---

> разделение на простая и указатель переменная

Создается ощущение, что вы думаете, что указатели отдельно, а все остальные объекты отдельно.

На самом деле, указатели - это *подвид* объектов, и на них действуют все те же правила, что и на остальные объекты.

Comment: Разве отсутствие имени подтверждает, что объекты не переменные? Не бьёт с [документацией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1466909)!

Comment: @cppbest И кидаете мне ссылку на мой же ответ. :р Не хочу углубляться в это, но пояснение добавлю.

Answer (score 1):

Когда мы создаем в программе переменную, например, типа int, мы резервируем в статической памяти 4 байта для ее хранения. Компилятор на этапе компиляции уже знает адрес, где искать эту переменную, поэтому больше 4 байт ему не потребуется. Но при создании переменных в куче, с помощью динамического выделения памяти (malloc и прочего), без дополнительной информации о местоположении уже не обойтись, ведь на этапе компиляции мы никак не можем знать, какое место в памяти нам подсунет система.

Comment: Если есть статья, где поподробнее расписано, я был бы рад ее прочитать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

Comment: Я взял из своих знаний, в которых, конечно, на безупречную правоту не претендую. Не знаю насколько подробно вас интересует природа этих явлений, я рассказал как знал.

Answer (score 1):

Есть три основных типа хранилища (*storage class*): **стек** (локальное), **куча** (динамическое) и **статическое**, а также ещё особняком есть память для **код**а:

- Если переменная хранится в куче, то указатель должен быть, без него никак, иначе будет *утечка памяти*.
- Если хранится в статической памяти, то память для неё резервируется на этапе компиляции и выделяется до запуска `main`.
- Если переменная стековая, то тут уже зависит от оптимизаций. Раньше даже было *ключевое слово* `register`. У регистровых переменных нельзя было брать адрес даже при условии, что это не требование, а совет компилятору.
- Код тоже хранится в памяти. Можно брать адрес функций.

Собственно, когда вы пишете имя переменной, то вы обращаетесь к какому-то адресу, т.к. имена переменных - это абстракция. Поэтому всё имеет адрес: либо в RAM (на самом деле в *виртуальной памяти*), либо где-то в *кэше процессора*, или даже в *регистрах*. Но получить адрес вы можете только для объектов в RAM.

Любая переменная **не** занимает 8 байт. Адрес любого объекта занимает место в памяти. Кроме того, 8 байт актуальны только для 64-битных систем, и то не во всех случаях:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    void method() {}
    int data{37};
};

int main() {
    A a;
    std::cout << sizeof(&a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(&A::data) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(&A::method) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Предполагаемый вывод:

```
8
16
16
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145993/discussion-on-answer-by-megorit---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.